# How can I center a table row with inline styles?

Tags: html, html-table, centering, inline-styles

I have this table row here that needs to be centered for a template I have to fix (the table row element is embedded in another table).

The problem for me is that I have to do this via inline styling because the code otherwise gets messed up by our abysmal backend "EmailBuilder".

Now I already tried `style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"` but it does absolutely nothing and I just want to have the whole row element smack dab in the middle of the screen.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```html
<tr>
  <td class="ns l-gray plr-5 pb-30" style="padding:0px 0 20px 8px; border-bottom:2px solid #e5e5e5;">
    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th align="left" class="flex" style="font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;" width="170">Test Street 5<br /> 81667 Test<br /> Test
          </th>
          <th class="flex" height="10" width="5">&nbsp;</th>
          <th align="left" class="flex" style="font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;" width="200">Tel: <a href="tel:1234567890" style="color:#b7b7b7; text-decoration:none;">1234567890
                            22</a><br /> Fax: 1234567890<br /> E-Mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.test" style="color:#b7b7b7; text-decoration:none;">Test@Mail.de</a>
          </th>
          <th class="flex" height="10" width="40">&nbsp;</th>
          <th align="left" class="flex" style="font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;">
            Test Location: Test<br /> CEO: Test Test
            <br /> USt-ID: Test 123459</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you really have enough Desktop Outlook users to justify compromising the email experience _for everyone else_? (Personally I'd _do it properly_ and use Conditional Comments to show an Open-in-browser link for Outlook users rather than tear any more hair out trying to accomodate them).

Comment: I really don't have a choice in this matter. My boss uses Outlook and I can't convince him otherwise. He really wants this fixed "his" way.

Comment: When you say "centered" - do you mean horizontally, vertically, or both? Also, you should remove all occurrences of `align="left|right|center"` from your HTML and replace it with `text-align: left|right|center;` inside `style=""`.

Comment: Centered in all directions would be preferable. This Block is more or less the footer of the Template and displays the Address and Details of the company. And yea all the "align=" elements are relics from this antiquated E-Mail Template. I didn't want to touch most of the inline stylings for fear of breaking it even more. It's already like a freaking Jenga Tower of antiquated HTML code.

Comment: It's not clear _which_ row you want centered, nor _how_ you want it centered. What does that mean? Text aligned to center in each cell? Cells crammed to the middle? Something else? Please revise to remove the ambiguity there.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this annoying problem by giving each `<th>` tag a `width="33%"` to evenly distribute the `<th>` Elements over the whole Table, which then makes them appear centered on the screen. If one wants the `<th>` elements closer to each other, one can just shrink down the whole `<table>` element with something like this `<table style="margin: auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" width="50%">`

Overall here is the fixed and centered HTML code.

```html
<tr>
  <td class="ns l-gray plr-5 pb-30"
      style="padding:0px 0 20px 8px; border-bottom:2px solid #e5e5e5;">
    <table style="margin: auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" width="50%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="flex" style="text-align: center; font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;" width="33%">
            Test Street 5<br /> 81667 Test<br /> Test
          </th>
          <th class="flex" style="text-align: center; font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;" width="33%">
            Tel: <a href="tel:1234567890" style="color:#b7b7b7; text-decoration:none;">1234567890 22</a><br />
            Fax: 1234567890<br />
            E-Mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.test" style="color:#b7b7b7; text-decoration:none;">Test@Mail.de</a>
          </th>
          <th class="flex" style="text-align: center; font:400 12px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Ubuntu; color:#b7b7b7; vertical-align:bottom;" width="33%">
            Test Location: Test<br />
            CEO: Test Test<br />
            USt-ID: Test 123459
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```